# Nothing in MaybeT monad: more concise way?

Tags: haskell, monads

I'm experimenting with the `MaybeT` monad, specifically `MaybeT Identity String`

```
import Control.Monad.Trans.Maybe
import Control.Monad.Identity
import Data.Maybe

main :: IO ()
main = putStrLn . show . runIdentity . runMaybeT $ maybeGetString

maybeGetString :: MaybeT Identity String
maybeGetString = return "first" >>
                 maybeTNothing >> 
                 return "second"

maybeTNothing :: MaybeT Identity String
maybeTNothing = MaybeT $ return Nothing
```

The experession for the `MaybeT` equivalent of `Nothing` seems to be `MaybeT $ return Nothing`, which feels a bit verbose, and it feels unexpected to me to have to explicitly use the `MaybeT` constructor.

Is there a shorter/nicer/clearer way of writing `Nothing` in the `MaybeT` monad?

Comment: [`mzero` from `Control.Monad`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:mzero)

Comment: [empty from Control.Applicative, the same but more general](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#v:empty)

Comment: @luqui Feel free to put an answer!

Comment: @Gurkenglas  Also free to put an answer!

Answer (score 3):

Inspired by the comment from @luqui

---

To behave as `Nothing` in the plain `Maybe` monad, `maybeTNothing` should satisfy the equations

```
maybeTNothing >>= f  =  maybeTNothing
v >> maybeTNothing   =  maybeTNothing
```

This is exactly the requirements on [`mzero`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#t:MonadPlus) from `MonadPlus`, which `MaybeT` is an instance of. So we can just use `mzero`

```
maybeTNothing = mzero
```

---

https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#t:MonadPlus